Logging Issues when converting a List to its single Members
I want to log this:
public async Task<List<TodoItemDTO>> GetTodos()
{
    var todoItems = await _todoItemRepository.GetTodoItems();
        

    Log.Information($"{todoItems}", todoItems);

        
    return todoItems.Select(t => ItemToDto(t)).ToList();
}

I'm expecting an array with multiple ToDoItems inside but get this as a return.
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NettoTemplateTodoAPIProjekt.Domain.Entities.TodoItem]

I tried converting it to a string:
Log.Information(string.Join("todoItems", todoItems.ToArray()))

And also tried to just turn it into an Array:
Log.Information(todoItems.ToArray()))


well, you need to ToString the elements in the array as well, not just the array itself. However how you convert your objects to string, depends on yourself.

You need log the list data, Then simply convert list to json string then save it.

Serilog will format the items, remove the string interpolation.
public async Task<List<TodoItemDTO>> GetTodos()
{
    var todoItems = await _todoItemRepository.GetTodoItems();
        

    Log.Information("@{TodoItems}", todoItems);

        
    return todoItems.Select(t => ItemToDto(t)).ToList();
}

